# Run Macro to different work sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have two excel file one is a.xlsm contains macro and another is b.xlsx contains various sheet eg (shee1,sheet2,sheet3 etc.)
my requirement is when i open a.xlsm file ,macro should open b.xlsx goto sheet2 and export as pdf.
i have tried following code

```
Sub Macro4()
'
' Macro4 Macro
'

'
    Sheets("Sales Contract").Select
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
        "E:\Universal Metals\Workspace\Universal_Metals\data-out\clover_output.pdf", _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas _
        :=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
    Windows("Book1").Activate
End Sub
```

Please advice as i am new to macro.

Answer (score 1):

You have to write the code in 'Workbook_Open' event of 'a.xlsm' file as given below
Hope it works

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()   
Dim xlwb As Workbook     

Set xlwb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\b.xlsx")    
xlwb.Sheets("Sales Contract").ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _    
        "E:\Universal Metals\Workspace\Universal_Metals\data-out\clover_output.pdf", _     
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas _    
        :=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True    

End Sub
```